# Entity Framework : get multiple rows with same ID

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Please help. I am using Entity Framework to get a list of records from a table where i have a matching applicable grade id as shown in this screenshot:

[Image showing the table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQDWu.jpg)

For instance, I want to get all the Name for applicable grade A which should return Banking, Hospitality and Information technology.

What I have tried:

```
foreach (var value in values)
{
    var geter = await _repository.gradeRepository
                                 .FindAsync(x => x.ApplicableGrade == "A");

    if (geter != null)
    {
        gradenames.Add(geter.Name);
    }
}
```

I am using a foreach statement to iterate through the list of data and adding to a List.

My issue: for each applicable `A`, it finds it keeps adding the first `Name` which is `Banking` instead. So my list at the end will contain `Banking, Banking, Banking` instead of `Banking, Hospitality, Information Technology`.

I have tried `.FirstOrDefaultAsync` and it repeats same.

How can I get the next name for same applicable grade?

Comment: Your question title says _"Entity framework Get Multiple Records with same ID"_ - but I don't see how the body of your post has anything to do with the title...

Comment: I am using a generic repository. __repository.gradeRepository.FindAsync(x => x.ApplicableGrade == "A");

Comment: Right, but `ApplicableGrade` isn't an `ID` value here.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is always returning "Banking" because on the Find definition it loops into the elements of the collection and then returns the first element that matches with the predicate.

The Find method should always be used with some predicates that always match on a single value (for example an Id) in this case I recommend you try to match your data with some other field.

I don't know what is in your "values" collection, maybe it has some useful data in order to solve this problem.

Also, you can use the Where method to get all the elements with Grade "A" and just loop it.

For your information this is the Find definition:

```
 public T Find(Predicate<T> match)
    {
        if (match == null)
        {
            ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.match);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < _size; i++)
        {
            if (match(_items[i]))
            {
                return _items[i];
            }
        }

        return default(T);
    }
```

Comment: I am abit confused because my repository FindAsync uses the where(predicate) 

        public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> FindAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return await _context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
    }